# preg_replace troubles

Tags: preg-replace

I am struggling with this regular expression.

```
$glossary_search[] = "/(^|>|\\s)".$glossary["glossary_name"]."($|<|\\s)/i";
$glossary_replace[] = "\$1<a href='/jargon-buster/".tapestry_hyphenate($glossary["glossary_name"]).".html' title='".$glossary["glossary_name"]."' target='_blank'>".$glossary["glossary_name"]."</a>\$2";

return preg_replace($glossary_search,$glossary_replace,$text);
```

I am trying to replace words in a product description with a hyperlink. The code above works if the word has a space either side but does not work if it has a full stop, comma or "<". Can anyone spot my mistake?

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: Can you provide a simple line of input and the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need to use `preg_quote` and `htmlentities`?

```
$glossary_search[] = "/(^|>|\\s)".preg_quote(htmlentities($glossary["glossary_name"],ENT_COMPAT,'UTF8'))."($|<|\\s)/i";
$glossary_replace[] = "\$1<a href='/jargon-buster/".tapestry_hyphenate($glossary["glossary_name"]).".html' title='".$glossary["glossary_name"]."' target='_blank'>".$glossary["glossary_name"]."</a>\$2";

return preg_replace($glossary_search,$glossary_replace,$text);
```

Comment: Hi Benjie, Thanks for your input. It does work but only to the same extent as the original code. When anything appears directly after the word it doesn't work. On it's own and it works perfectly.

Comment: Can you give an example of that $glossary variable and the $text variables that do and do not work?

Comment: Hi Benji, Thanks for your response. It turns out that during my debugging that I inadvertently forgot that I had duplicated the code in my script. Turns out that it was working all along but was giving the wrong output because it was being initiated twice. Another reason why it's a bad idea to trouble shoot late at night! Thanks again for your help!